# ¿Por que obtengo un error de json no válido en la siguiente petición POST?

Tags: swift, swift4

Buenos dias estoy tratando de realizar una petición POST a un web service, el json que estoy utilizando es :

{
"usuario": 1066,
"password": 123
}

Pero siempre obtengo como resultado el siguiente error :

dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

¿Cual es la causa de este error?

Gracias

```
internal func request(message:String,api:String) throws -> String {
    guard let url = URL.init(string: self.url + api)else{
        throw PostClientErrors.invalidURL
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url )

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    guard let data = message.data(using: .ascii) else{
        throw PostClientErrors.encodingDataError
    }

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data){
        data, response, error in

        self.error = nil
        if let error = error{
            self.error = PostClientErrors.urlSessionError(error)
            self.end = true
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200{
            self.end = true
            self.error = PostClientErrors.httpError(httpStatus)
            return
        }


        guard let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) else{
            self.end = true
            self.error = PostClientErrors.decodingDaraError
            return
        }

        self.data = self.dataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.dataString = string
        self.end = true
    }
    task.resume()

    while !self.end{
        print (task.state.rawValue)
    }
    return dataString
}
```

Comment: has probado antes en postman? si no funciona en postman no funciona en las apps, de lo contrario seria checar que le esta llegando al backend, trata de hacer unos breakpoints justo cuando le mandas los datos al requestPost.

Comment: ¿Has  probado a hacer un parseo del JSON?

Comment: Parece que el json que estás utilizando va dentro de un objeto llamado user info, todo indica de que tienes que averiguar el body exacto del método que estás consumiendo

Answer (score 0):

de acuerdo a la descripción del error que te lanza yo intentaría poner el json dentro de un array, o sea, agregarle paréntesis rectos al inicio y al final, así:

```
[{ "usuario": 1066, "password": 123 }]
```

Comment: Ya lo intente me resulta el mismo error